# Leetcode - Check If N and Its Double Exist

Tags: java, arrays

https://leetcode.com/problems/check-if-n-and-its-double-exist/

```
public boolean checkIfExist(int[] arr) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == 2 * arr[j]) {
                    return true; 
                } else if (arr[i] / 2 == arr[j] && arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                    return true; 
                } else {
                    continue; 
                }
            }
        }
        return false; 
    }
```

this is what I have so far, but I can't figure out why I'm keep getting "false".

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You're testing the same twice, either change from multiplication to division or from left to right, not both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your problem

You checked the same condition 2 times:

if `N is 2x larger than M` done with `arr[i] == 2 * arr[j]`

if `M is 2x smaller than N` - done with `arr[i] / 2 == arr[j]` 
it's the same thing.

#### Solution

You made a problem way too hard with that approach of comparison. If one has to be 2x larger than the other, then check if `2N == M` or `2M == N`. And that's it.

```
public boolean checkIfExist(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == 2 * arr[j] || arr[j] == 2 * arr[i]) {
                return true; 
            }
            //no need for continue as there is no code to skip in this iteration
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

`continue` is needed only to skip part of the code in the iteration and jump to the next one. `continue` at the end of the loop block is useless.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike!

Comment: @sunykim NP, these things come with experience.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution with a minimal update passed:

```java
    public boolean checkIfExist(int[] arr) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == 2 * arr[j] || 2 * arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    return true; 
                }
            }
        }
        return false; 
    }
```

Possibly, it's worth to check if there's no even number in the input array and return false but it's a minor optimization.

---

**Update**

A solution based on a `HashMap` should have less complexity.  Here the map values are lists of element indexes in the input array.

```
public boolean checkIfExists(int ... arr) {
    boolean hasEven = false;
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(arr[i], (key) -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
        hasEven |= arr[i] % 2 == 0;
    }
        
    return hasEven && (map.containsKey(0) && map.get(0).size() > 1 // check multiple 0's
            || map.entrySet().stream()
                  .anyMatch(e -> map.containsKey(2 * e.getKey()) 
                      && !e.getValue().equals(map.get(2 * e.getKey()))
                  ));
}
```

Comment: dude, it's exactly the same code as mine :D

Comment: Yes, and what's surprized me most is that it's able to pass the check on Leet with O(N^2) complexity without exceeding time limit